# What is the best formatting for operator placements on new lines?

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, formatting

For operations on multiple lines, most of the time, i see and use this formatting:

```
result = object->someValue() +
    variable -
    function(array) * (arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4);
```

But i sometimes find this one:

```
result = object->someValue()
    + variable 
    - function(array) * (arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4);
```

Same problem for conditions:

```
if ((conditionA && conditionB) ||
    (conditionC ^ conditionD))
```

versus

```
if ((conditionA && conditionB)
    || (conditionC ^ conditionD))
```

I think the one with operator on newline is more readable, but far less common. Which one would you advise ?

Comment: This'll boil down to a religious war, so voting to close as not constructive. There's no One True Style, just as there's no One True Style for bracket placement.

Comment: It is all personal preference and thus no 'correct' answer can be given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to note that this is not necessarily a matter of personal preference. In some languages, it is *objectively* better to have one style instead of another.

For example, some languages use automatic semicolon insertion. That means that

```
a = 1 - 2 - 3 -
4 - 5 - 6;
```

could mean something different than

```
a = 1 - 2 - 3
- 4 - 5 - 6;
```

Because the first will be interpreted as

```
a = 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6;
```

But the second could be interpreted as

```
a = 1 - 2 - 3;
-4 - 5 - 6; //useless expression statement
```

That means, depending on which style you use, `a` could be set to either -19 or -4;

In most languages, it doesn't matter, and it really is just a matter of personal preference, but in some languages, such as Javascript, which use automatic semicolon insertion, the first style is preferable.

Comment: Fully agreed. I found that your particular example here does not trigger JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion. The value of `a` ends up being 19 in both cases, as one would expected. Further information about this topic can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion