# Recommendations about placement of logical operators in multiline condition expressions

Tags: language-agnostic, code-formatting

This is really a detailed formatting question, but I stumble over it every time...

For multiline condition expressions what placement of the logical operators is preferred?

---

**Alternative 1: logical operators at the end of each line**

```
if (value1 == comparision1 &&
    value2 != comparision2 &&
    !comparision3.Contains(value3))
{
    // stuff
}
```

**Pro:** lines are beautifully aligned

**Con:** logical operators are missed easily

---

**Alternative 2: logical operators at the beginning of each line**

```
if (value1 == comparision1
    && value2 != comparision2
    && !comparision3.Contains(value3))
{
    // stuff
}
```

**Pro:** logical operators are strongly present

**Con:** alignment looks weird

---

What do you prefer?
What formatting did helped you in the past?
What formatting did confused you in the past?

---

**Edit:**

Just found a related question I did not found before (though I searched intensively): [What is the best formatting for operator placements on new lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259398/what-is-the-best-formatting-for-operator-placements-on-new-lines)

It seems to be generally accepted that the placement of operators are completely up to personal opinions (with the one exception that is outlined in the answer over there), but I do not agree to this. Due to the arguments I wrote as Pro/Con, there is definitely an impact on code readability!

The remaining problem: I have no personal opinion and am unsure therefore what style to chose, every time I come to such a situation. Obviously being difficult to be rated theoretically, I asked for your practical experiences you made in the past with this kind of expressions.

Comment: don't put complex condition in `if` statement. extract it to separate function/method

Comment: Sorry, but this question is about the placement of logical operators and not about using multiline if conditions. If I would have been interested in recommendations about using multiline if conditions or not, I would have asked: is it recommended to use multiline if conditions?

Comment: Even when the complex condition is in a separate method, the question still stands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguments for placing logical operators on a new line.
parts copied from: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7975386

- They line up below the first statement (or expression), it's easier to see which lines are continuations of the previous ones
- you can add a new clause without needing to edit an existing line, makes for cleaner diffs during reviews and makes it such that you wouldn't show up as the last person who touched the existing line in git blame or any other source control equivalent.
- easier to comment out lines of code (because of the last line)
- GNU Coding Standards, section 5.1 Formatting Your Source Code:

  When you split an expression into multiple lines, split it before an operator, not after one. Here is the right way:

  `if (foo_this_is_long && bar > win (x, y, z)`
      `&& remaining_condition)`

  https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Formatting.html

Comment: Thank you for this input. These thoughts are exactly what I was looking for. IMHO these aren't opinion based views, but objective arguments!

Answer (score 3):

There is no best format. Use the standard of your team. If you aren't on a team or are charged with defining a standard for your team, pick whatever makes the code easiest to read. Clarity is the most important thing to consider.

It doesn't really matter nearly as much *which* format you choose. What matters most is that you and your team are *consistent* in using the format. If all of your code follows the same pattern, the code will be easier to read than if you had no standard at all.

Comment: Good approach. On our team I am the one that tries to push standards the most. Because there is always much criticism, I want to try to approve a new standard proposal as much as I can - which is why you find me worrying about details here... due to the lack of my ability to identify which alternative provides more clarity, I ask for practical experiences over here.

Comment: @Nicolas: It's not particularly important to know what strangers that will never see your code think is correct. What's important is what _you_ and _your team_ think is most clear. After all, you're the ones reading the code.  The point is to make the code easier for _you_ to read. And honestly, it doesn't matter all that much as long as you are consistent across your code base. Even if you pick the worst format possible, as long as you do it everywhere, the pattern will be familiar to everyone which will make it easy to comprehend.